# Excel oledb connection to Ms-Access database lock access db

Tags: excel

I have an excel spreadsheet that connects to MS-Access 2003 database using ole db connection. When I refresh the data in spreadsheet and open my ms-access database it says database is read-only. If I close the spreadsheet and then open MS-Access DB then it opens in Write mode. The following is the connection string used in Excel spreadsheet.

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Password="";User ID=Admin;
Data Source=D:\Dev\Reports.mdb;Mode=Share Deny Write;Extended Properties="";
Jet OLEDB:System database="";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="";
Jet OLEDB:Database Password="";
Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;
Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;
Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;
Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;
Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False
```

Comment: Do you how to accept answers? You should accept right answers, before asking new ones.

Comment: I didn't get any valid answer that solved problem

Comment: @hgulyan I would be glad of a link to the previous question.

Comment: @Remou He has asked 7 questions in SO with no accepted answers. Is that ok for you?

Comment: @hgulyan I just wanted to check that I was not giving the same answer as you gave. @Kannabiran does not seem to be working in the spirit of SO.

Comment: @Remou, That's why I tried to figure out if he knows the rules. He should know why mostly so's doesn't answer to this kind of questions.

Comment: @Remou, @hgulyan - could you please tell me the rules of SO? I have posted some questions and I didnt get a suitable answer... So what should I do. Do I need to mark the answer as "not useful"

Answer (score 19):

Change `"Mode=Share Deny Write"` to `"Mode=Read"`

in connection string

Comment: For a list of all modes https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210191

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that the Excel user has full permissions on the folder containing the Access file?

Comment: I have found the solution... we need to set mode=read; in the connection string... that solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Excel's background refresh option is enabled. Disable it, or use the query studio to design the query as DBQ.

```
<xml id=msodc><odc:OfficeDataConnection xmlns:odc="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:odc"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <odc:Connection odc:Type="ODBC">
    <odc:ConnectionString>
    DBQ=<database path and filename>;DefaultDir=<database path>;
    Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DriverId=25;
    FIL=MS Access;MaxBufferSize=2048;MaxScanRows=8;PageTimeout=5;
    ReadOnly=1;SafeTransactions=0;Threads=3;UID=admin;UserCommitSync=Yes;
    </odc:ConnectionString>
  <odc:CommandText>SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... </odc:CommandText>
  </odc:Connection>
</odc:OfficeDataConnection></xml>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using older versions of Excel (like me with Excel 2003), which don't have the GUI connection string option:

First save the query as `.dqy`, then open the saved file with your beloved text editor. Add the `Mode` key alongside the others (the line above the actual SQL query string, and don't forget the `;`)

You have to use the numerical value instead of the string value:

| Numerical | String |
| --- | --- |
| `Mode=0x1` | `Mode=Read` |
| `Mode=0x2` | `Mode=Write` |
| `Mode=0x3` | `Mode=ReadWrite` |
| `Mode=0x4` | `Mode=Share Deny Read` |
| `Mode=0x8` | `Mode=Share Deny Write` |
| `Mode=0xC` | `Mode=Share Exclusive` |
| `Mode=0x10` | `Mode=Share Deny None` |

Credit to [@Slai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1383168/slai) who provided the [link to the documentation of the numeric values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210191).